# Dimple.js how to customize range of values on Y-axis from 0 to 100?

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I need to customize the y-axis value range to start from 0 till 100. I do not want the automated range that Dimple.js adds based on the data that I have. Please suggest if its possible. I tried the `x.overrideMax`but it is messing the bar/line plot.

Answer (score 6):

Using overrideMax should work.  In your question you write that you tried `x.overrideMax` is that a typo in the question?  It should be `y.overrideMax` for the y axis:

```
y.overrideMax = 100;
```

Comment: Don't forget to include `y.overrideMin = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

First declare a variable for y-axis, then override max and min values. Please see the example below:

```
  var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Horsepower");
  y.overrideMin = 0;
  y.overrideMax = 250;
```